# Java: Finding the smallest greater than zero number in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Finding smallest number is easy. I am finding it difficult to find a smallest greater than zero number in an array.

```
public static int findSmallestOld(int[] arr) {
    int smallest = arr[0];
    for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i]<smallest) {
            smallest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Few example inputs could be 
{0, 0, 0, 3} output = 3
{0, 1, 0, 4} output = 1

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: You could sort the array first with Collections.sort(arr) and then just return the first number which is greater 0.

Comment: You can change `(arr[i]<smallest)` to `(arr[i]<smallest && arr[i] > 0)`

Comment: That would still be problematic if the first value of the array is e.g. -2.

Comment: Do not start with `smallest = arr[0]` but `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead, then loop from 0.

Comment: @Bram so, how would you later on state that the array either had no valid numbers, or had (at least) one with the value of Integer.MAX_VALUE ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static int findSmallest(int[] arr) {
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > 0 && arr[i]<smallest) {
            smallest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

At the end, if smallest == Integer.MAX_VALUE, then all the array is filled of zeros.

Comment: The loop should start at 0 though.

Comment: fluminis: what if one of the elements of the array has Integer.MAX_VALUE as value? it's better to have the default value to be negative, and verify that the result is higher than 0

Comment: @Stultuske that won't work because you can't have a value that is bigger then `0` and smaller then a negative number which means that the `if` condition will always be `false`.

Comment: @Titus: at which point the code will not behave how it should for all values.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
if(arr[i]<smallest)
```

to

```
if(arr[i]<smallest && arr[i] > 0)
```

otherwise it will be overwritten by any value, whether it is a positive int or not.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

    int[] numbers = {12,20,85,40,95,54,75,45,50,43,11,9,5,6};
    int temp = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] <  temp) {
            temp = numbers[i] ;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
if(arr[i]<smallest && arr[i]>0) {
    smallest = arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    int[] numbers = {12,20,85,40,95,54,75,45,50,43,11,9,5,6};
    if (numbers.length > 0) {
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
    }
    System.out.println(numbers[0]);
```

or

```
int minimum = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] < minimum){
            minimum=numbers[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The minimum in an array is "+minimum);
}
```